# Showing objects in web page in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to show all the data that I have saved in my admin page to users visiting my website.

models.py:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_of_release=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    IMDb=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cast=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    summary=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    image=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want the movie name to be shown to users and when they click on the name it takes them to another page that contain all the information about the movie.

Any ideas?

Comment: Great idea, where would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

An example is below.

urls.py:

```py
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('movies/', views.movies, name='movies'),
    path('movies/<int:id>/',views.single_movie, name='single_movie')
]
```

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def movies(request):
    items = Movie.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'some_folder_name/movies.html', {'movies':items})

def single_movie(request,id):
    one_movie=get_object_or_404(Movie, id=id)
    return render(request,'some_folder_name/single_movie.html', {'movie':one_movie})
```

movies.html:

```html
<body>
    {% for movie in movies %}
        <a href="{% url 'single_movie' movie.id %}"> Name : {{movie.name}} </a>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

single_movie.html:

```html
<body>
    {% if movie %}
        <h1>Information of {{movie.name}}</h1>
        <p> genre: {{movie.genre}} </p>
        <p> Date of release: {{movie.date_of_release}} </p>
        <p> Cast: {{movie.cast}} </p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Similarly, you can show all the information of clicked movie in `single.movie.html` page.